# Grab first occurrence of a bbcode

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all, bbcode

I originally have this `preg_match_all` pattern for the HTML `img` tag, but how do I find the first occurrence for a bbcode?

`$output = preg_match_all('/<img.+src=[\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"].*>/i', $content, $matches);`

`[img]http://path/to/img.png[/img]`

Which should return the content of the `[img]` bbcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this :**

```
\[img\]([^\[\]\'"]+)\[\/img\]
```

**Demo :**

http://regexr.com?30mks

Comment: May I know why your answrs are different.

Comment: @JackSpairow Michael's `[^\[]+` tries to get what's between `[img]` and `[/img]` by not allowing the `[`s in it. While mine, does the same thing without allowing : `[`s, `]`s, `'`s (single quotes) and `"`s (double quotes). Plus, I'm also CAPTURING the string within `[img]` tags in a group so that you can do whatever you wish with it; just retrieve it? replace it? whatever... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
\[img\][^\[]+\[\/img\]
```